# Color of date tag in org-mode publish to HTML and boxes around text

Tags: html, publish, org-mode

I am using org-mode version 7.4 to organize all of my research notes and then export to HTML so I can create a sort of personal wiki. I just have two questions:

1) Upon export to HTML, the org-mode date stamps appear a very faint gray, is there anyway to change this this color to something more bold? If the fix involves adding a lot of messy CSS tags, is there something I could add to my .emacs file instead? I am hoping to keep my original org file as neat and as legible as possible.

2) Also, what is the best way to add a box around some text in org-mode? I have found that surrounding the text in #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp / #+END_SRC emacs-lisp tags works the same as #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE/#+END_EXAMPLE in that the org-mode features (like using an asterix to mark headings and -,+,. to mark sub-items) do not get evaluated in the block. I am interested in just being able to put a block around the text, but still have the org-mode features such as headings, sub-items, etc., be evaluated.

Thank you for the help, I admit I am a bit of a noob here.

**UPDATE:** Thank you to [Jonathan Leech-Pepin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857959/jonathan-leech-pepin) and [Juancho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605276/juancho) for the tips. Part 1 is definitely answered and I apologize for missing it in the manual.

For part 2, I realize I could wrap DIV tags in BEGIN_SRC HTML tags, but I was hopeful that there might be a simpler way of doing this, as it seems like something many people would want to do as a way of highlighting or offsetting text. I was hoping there was something equivalent to the BEGIN_EXAMPLE/END_EXAMPLE tags that I was simply missing. I can use the DIV tags, and will if need be, but it ends up making the original org file look a bit messy and illegible if you end up doing it a lot. So if anyone knows a shortcut, I'd be happy to hear it. I suppose if I knew what I was doing more, I could write my own function, which I may just end up looking into once I'm through my thesis proposal and actually have more free time. :)

Thanks Everyone!!!

Answer (score 4):

For point 1)

You can adjust the CSS settings either for a single file or create a custom stylesheet.

The relevant classes for style formatting are listed in the [Org Manual - CSS Support](http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html#CSS-support)

As a test I added (as a single line, the line return is to make it easier to read on the page)

```
#+STYLE: <style type="text/css"> .timestamp { color: purple; font-weight: bold; }
         </style>
```

to one of my org files and exported. The timestamps were a bold purple, which was much more legible.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Something up in export configuration options as opposed to in the body of the text itself. I have a custom stylesheet for my project, but was unsure how to call out just the timestamps specifically, and I want something that works even when it the org file is not part of the project. I apologize for missing this in the manual, but the org manual can be a bit overwhelming when you are just starting.

Comment: With Org mode 9.5.2 I had to use`#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css">.timestamp { color: purple; font-weight: bold; } </style>` instead of `#+STYLE: ...`

Answer (score 1):

The HTML exporter in org-mode adds `class` identifiers extensively, so that you can style your HTML at will.

Have a look at http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html

You don't need to include your CSS inside the document itself. You can either link to a stylesheet via the `#+STYLE` directive, or you can customize the default CSS that comes with org-mode.

As for question 2, have a look at an exported org-mode file. There are plenty of `div` sections that you can style via CSS, like adding a border.

Comment: Thanks, I've done a lot of div borders on my blog and I figured wrapping them inside #+BEGIN_SRC HTML tags in org-mode would be messy and a bit of a pain. Not that it wouldn't work, but I was just hoping that there might be a cleaner way of doing it that would keep the org file itself more legible. It seems such an obvious thing to want to do, I was hoping there was some type of built in functionality for it that I somehow missed in the manual. 

The manual is great but but it also can be easy to miss something when you are not used to computer coding or CSS scripting to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As another option if you prefer some trial and error as well as seeing an example vs. a specification is to download some examples and pay attention to what css elements are tweaked.

For example, I was recently trying to change the background color of exported tags in html and found [this org-mode mailing list thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-02/msg01429.html). I grabbed a copy of worg-original.css and searched it for the word 'tag':

```
.tag {
    color: #DDD;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

I didn't like the background and noticed other elements with a `background-color` property so I played with it and ended up with:

```
.tag {
   color: #000;
   background-color: #ccf;
   font-size: 85%;
   font-weight: 500;
   margin: 0 0 0 8em;
}
```

You can do the same for timestamp properties. I'd suggest finding some things you like and throwing them together in a .css file. From there you can just put the `#+style:` line in each file (as has already been mentioned):

```
#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/stylesheet.css" />
```

This isn't really anything new compared to the other answers; I mainly added it as another approach. I didn't know css, so seeing the list of properties in the org manual (p.author, .timestamp-kwd, .todo) didn't mean much to me. Finding a .css that was specifically designed for org-mode expert, such as those linked in the mailing list above for the org manual and worg were *much* more helpful since I could see some tangible examples and tweak from there.